# Couldn't understand how .reduce works in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I was doing JavaScript exercise and got this question:

Write a JavaScript function that accepts a string as a parameter and find the longest word within the string.
Example string : 'Web Development Tutorial' (Development)

I found a solution and it was like this:

```
function longest(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');

  return arr.reduce((a,b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "");
}

console.log(longest('Web Development Tutorial'));
```

The code above does work, but I couldn't understand 
`arr.reduce((a,b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "")` 
part.

Does it mean

```
reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (a.length < b.length) {
    b
  } else {
    a,
      "";
  }
}
```

which still doesn't make much sense?

Comment: It means `""` is default value of `a` for the first iteration, then next item in array is compared with it. The code is similar to `var longest = "";` then inside `for` loop `if (a.length < b.length) longest = b; else longest = a;`.

Comment: Read about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) and the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Conditional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some very good answers have been given. One way to look at what is happening is to put console.log. Just take a look at this code and you would know what is happening:

```js
function longest(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');

  return arr.reduce((a,b) => {
   console.log(`a=${a}, b=${b}`); 
   return a.length < b.length ? b : a;
  }, "");
}

console.log(longest('Web Development Tutorial'));
```

The output should be self explanatory.
However, if you are not aware of arrow functions or template string literals then you need to learn them first to understand the output.

Comment: Wow I've never think of console logging this! Thank you so much!

Comment: @kayak cheers! Treat console.log not just as a logging tool but a learning tool too.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `reduce` is the accumulator, which is either the value returned from the last callback, or the initial value (which is either the first argument in the array, or the second argument passed to `reduce`).

It's equivalent to the following:

```
function longest(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  let a = ''; // initial value
  arr.forEach((b) => {
    a = a.length < b.length ? b : a;
  });
  return a;
}
```

Or, removing the conditional operator:

```
function longest(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  let a = ''; // initial value
  arr.forEach((b) => {
    if (b.length > a.length) {
      a = b;
    }
  });
  return a;
}
```

Remember that when an arrow function lacks a `{` after `=>`, the expression that follows the `=>` will be implicitly returned, so

```
return arr.reduce((a,b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "");
```

is also equivalent to

```
return arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a.length < b.length ? b : a;
}, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` works kind of like a loop, involving a value (the current item in the array) and an accumulator (the value returned from the previous call to the function, or the second argument passed to `reduce`).

Since the purpose of `reduce` is to *reduce* the array into a single value, you can think of it like this:

```
let a = "";

arr.forEach(item => {
  if (a.length < b.length) {
    a = b;
  } else {
    a = a;
  }
});

return accumulator;
```

Note that the `else` statement is irrelevant in the above code, but it represents how `reduce` works. Try looking it up too - [this](https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-reduce-function-b2b0406efbdc?gi=4b2df425eda7) is a pretty good guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to rewrite the code using `if` it would be:

```
function longest (a, b) {
    if (a.length < b.length) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return a;
    }
}

return arr.reduce(longest, "");
```

Note that the second argument to reduce (the `""`) initializes the accumulator variable (the `a`) to that value (empty string) when reduce starts looping. The syntax is a bit confusing with arrow functions because it could be mistaken for the comma operator when in fact it is simply the comma separating arguments to `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` converts multiple (or indeterminate) values into a single value.

It starts with an initial value, which we'll call the "accumulator" and a binary function ("binary" meaning function with two formal parameters), which we'll call the "reducer". `reduce` applies the reducer to the accumulator and the first element of the list. The return value of the reducer function becomes the new accumulator. That's why we call it "accumulator", because it accumulates or gathers the results of the reducer. `reduce` repeats this process until there are no more elements in the list, and returns the last return value from the reducer.

Some applications:

## Summing a List of Numbers

```js
const add = (x, y) => x + y
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(add, 0)
// 10
```

In this case, `x` is the accumulator and `y` is the list element.
If we mentally execute this reducer, we'd have:

```
x: 0, y: 1
x: 1, y: 2
x: 3, y: 3
x: 6, y: 4
x: 10, STOP
```

## Counting Table Columns from a Table's Data Model

```js
const columnReducer = (tally, {layout}) => {
  const isFullLayout = layout === 'full'
  const isCompleteSemiLayout = tally.semiLayouts === 2
  const columns = isFullLayout || isCompleteSemiLayout ? tally.columns + 1 : tally.columns
  const semiLayouts  = 
      isCompleteSemiLayout ? 0
    : !isFullLayout ? tally.semiLayouts + 1
    : tally.semiLayouts

  return { columns, semiLayouts };
}

const { columns } = rows.reduce(columnReducer, { columns: 0, semiLayouts: 0});
```

## Tallying Items

```js
const materialsReducer = (items, { id, material }) => ({
  ...items,
  [material]: {
    tally: items[material] || 0 + 1,
    ids: [...items[material] || [], id]
  }
})

[
  { id: 1, material: 'wood' },
  { id: 2, material: 'gold' },
  { id: 3, material: 'wood' }
].reduce(materialsReducer, {})
// { wood: { tally: 2, ids: [1, 3] }, gold: { tally: 1, ids: [3] } }
```

`reduce` is 'declarative', meaning that you as the programmer describe the desired outcome. Contrast that with `for` loops, which are 'imperative', meaning that you as the programmer instruct the computer what to do in a step-by-step manner.